# Where Can I Buy Commercial Beer in Swing Top Bottles in UK

Tags: bottles, better-bottle

Where can I buy beer that comes in swing top bottles? I don't wanna buy empty bottles if for a few more coins I can get some beer in it! :D

Please list below Details like:

- Location
- Brand
- Size
- Cost
- Colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pubs that stock Grolsch will often let you have their bottles, for £4 per crate, which is a lot less than you would usually pay for empty bottles.  They have a deal with Grolsch to return the bottles (and crates) for that amount, but apparently Grolsch is awful at picking up regularly, so most places have a case or two, or sometimes 10, hanging around that they just want rid of, and if you offer to pay their refund, they will gladly take it.

I find the bottles to be perfect for brewing (if you don't mind Green bottles), they're strong and attractive, and you won't get them cheaper than this!

Comment: (Note, I haven't done this for about a year, the price may have gone up...)

Comment: I know only 1 place that sells them and they said they had to return them to the brewery, but I was trying to score them for free. I will try again armed with this knowledge. thanks

Comment: I had more luck with small restaurants than pubs, actually.  If you're in London, I can name some specific places.

Comment: I venture in quite often, anything along Stratford to Sidcup by car would be great.

Comment: I can get regular bottles from Wetherspoons, but not swing tops.

Comment: That part of London isn't my neck of the woods, I'm afraid.  There's some fairly funky pubs in Stratford that may help you, but none that I know will.  The ones I know are right in the center (Oxford Street-ish, try My Old Dutch), and one in King's Cross (The Lincoln Lounge).

Answer (score 0):

- Location: Aldi (Next shipment Sept 2014)
- Brand: Das Helle
- Size: 500ml *
- Cost: £2 approx
- Colour: Brown *

Answer (score 0):

- Location: Asda / Tesco
- Brand: Grolsch
- Size: 450ml
- Cost: 3 for £5 approx
- Colour: Green